# How to configure ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to store the photo in public external storage?

Tags: android, android-image-capture

The [Taking Photos Simply Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) recommends to store image taken with device camera as "should be saved on the device in the public external storage". But how to do this? The provided example shows rather how to save to a private folder!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this code it will help you definitely:

private void selectImage() {

```
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Maintenance.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            } /*else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }*/
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450, false);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                // byte[] imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
                // encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                Camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                //file.getPath();
                // String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
                image = file.getPath();
                String[] parts = image.split("/");
                encodedImage = parts[parts.length - 1];
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 450, 450, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bytes);
            //  byte[] imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
            // encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            image = picturePath;
            String[] parts = picturePath.split("/");
            encodedImage = parts[parts.length - 1];
            Camera.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though looks like by keeping the file object I don't need to search for it in onActivityResult.

Comment: ya that's upon you because you know the flow of your code.

Answer (score 1):

> The provided example shows rather how to save to a private folder!?

No, it does not. It shows how to save to `getExternalFilesDir()`. This is part of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which the user can access.

You are also welcome to create yourself a subdirectory under `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, if you prefer. You will need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on all API levels, though, including needing to set up runtime permissions on Android 6.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//Click Picture from camera
        camera_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CLICK_RESULT);

            }


        });
```

Heres the result

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Get Image from Camera
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CLICK_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap photo = null;
        try {
            photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 900);


        try {
            //Write file
            String filename = "/file_name";
            String dir_path = "Directory_Path";
            File file = new File(dir_path)
            file.mkdir();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dir_path + filename);
            selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);

            //Cleanup
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

//Resize Bitmap
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: This works too but wasn't able to get rotation information with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Action Image Capture method:

```
// OPEN CAMERA & TAKE PIC
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    try {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            // Create the File where the photo should go
            //File photoFile = null;

            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("takePic_IO_EX", ex + "");
            }

            //photoFile = createImageFile();

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.appname.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);


                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    this.grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                /*takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                this.setResult(RESULT_OK, takePictureIntent);*/


                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("takePic_main_EX", e + "");
    }

}
```

onActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        try {

            /*Log.e("mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Log.e("displayPic", "2");
            attendanceCameraBtn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.e("displayPic", "3");*/

            try {
                if (photoFile.getAbsoluteFile().getTotalSpace() <= 10) {
                    //Log.e("fileSize==2==", photoFile.getTotalSpace() + "    ++++");
                    if (photoFile.isFile()) {
                        if (photoFile.exists()) {
                            photoFile.delete();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo Capture Failed, Please Retry!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                } else {


                            //Do whatever you want here
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("file", e + "");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("displayPic_EX", e + "");
            Log.e("onActivityResult_EX", e + "");
        }
    } else {

        try {
            if (photoFile.isFile()) {
                if (photoFile.exists()) {
                    photoFile.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo Capture Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("onActivityResult_els_EX", e + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Create image Directory and Image file in `private folder` method:

```
 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    Random generate = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generate.nextInt(n);

    String nValue = String.valueOf(n);
    String fName = "Image-" + n;


    String filePath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File dir = new File(filePath + "/app_images");

    if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            fName,          /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            dir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath + "  ++++"); //Prints you the image file path
    return image;
}



try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("takePic_IO_EX", ex + "");
            }
```

And create a folder named `xml` inside your `res` folder. Inside that `xml` folder, create an `xml file` and name it `file_paths.xml`. Mention this path inside `file_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Images" path="Android/data/" />
</paths>
```

Declare `File photoFile` globally.
All the best!