# Unable to capture image using camera intent in samsung note 3

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

It's may be an old question but I couldn't find any solution for my issue. So asking it again

I am trying to capture an image and store it in internal storage and after usage in my app I am deleting it. It is working fine in all devices but in Samsung Note 3.

```
private void captureImage() {
        try {
            if(photoPath!=null) {
                new File(photoPath).delete();
                photoPath = null;
            }
            //SET THE IMAGE NAME AND IMAGE PATH FOR THE CURRENT IMAGE 
            final Random random = new Random();
            photoPath = getPath(this)+"/img" + String.valueOf(random.nextInt()) + ".jpg";
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final File imageStorage = new File(photoPath);
            if (imageStorage != null) {
                //to capture full image use URI otherwise use filepath
                 Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "<<my path>>.fileprovider", imageStorage);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.ACTION_CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
    }
}
```

Is anything I am missing here. Please can anybody help me

Comment: Try the code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45051355/4116560) link. It works great!

Answer (score -2):

**In Manifeast.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

is mandatory in order to use the camera (I'm not using camera via Intent, I have a customize camera app)

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" 
android:required="false" />
```

android:required="false" means Google Play will not prevent the application from being installed to devices that do not include these camera features - so the user having a device without camera and camera flash will be able to install the app from market.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html