# Android Camera picture not showing in ImageView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-camera-intent

I am trying to take a picture with the camera of "Nexus 5X API 26" and show it in `ImageView` field, before uploading it to Firebase.

First problem is that after taking a picture, it does not show up in `imageView`. I am doing the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);}
```

And then I was trying to show the picture in the same way I do for the pictures taken from Gallery:

```
filePath = data.getData();
   try {
      Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The part which I do not understand is how `data.getData()` works in both cases (for Gallery and for Camera)?

I guess that the `uploadImage()` method, should be the same for both Gallery and Camera uploads (it works for Gallery already so...).

So the thing that I am currently missing is that I am not getting the `filePath`, I guess? 
Is it necessary to "temporarily save" the camera's picture in order to `.getData()`? Or it can work without any kind of "saving"?

I just want the user to take a picture and it should be sent to Firebase. Not necessary for user to see it in `imageView` first, just to get the uri (data) in order to upload it.

[view when i open the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdxHN.png)
     [view after taking a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/misR6.png)

Comment: There's probably an Exception being thrown. Check what your catch block prints.

Comment: `getData()` works entirely differently for camera intent. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715056/192373 and links around that. Usually, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046001/how-to-configure-action-image-capture-to-store-the-photo-in-public-external-stor, we pass EXTRA_OUTPUT to tell the camera app where to store the picture. Instead, you can [get the last picture taken by camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557147/192373) in **onActivityResult()**.

Comment: Thanks, the posts + further refinement worked out in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```java
Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       startActivityForResult(intent,7);


     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


                    bitmap= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageEncoded.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAsBytes);
            bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);


        }
```

Comment: first you test on small image and then on large image then send the screen shot of the problem